# std::rethrow_exception(nullptr) undefined behavior or bad_exception?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, nullptr, rethrow

I have a code snippet where I call rethrow_exception with nullptr as argument.
The documentation says the argument should be non-null, but I want to know, if I pass nullptr, is the behavior undefined or known?

I am getting bad_exception everytime. However, this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/rethrow_exception/) says the behavior is undefined.

```
std::string msg;
    try
    {
        std::rethrow_exception(nullptr);
    }
    catch (std::bad_exception &ex)
    {
        msg = ex.what();
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        msg = ex.what();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        msg = "uncaught exception!";
    }
```

Anyone, who can comment upon what exactly happens?

Comment: Undefined behaviour can be *anything*. You can't determine that a program *doesn't* have undefined behaviour by inspecting its behaviour.

Comment: molbdnilo yeah.. I undertsand that, I wanted to know what the C++ standard says. @Max pointed out what I needed.

Comment: @Ishita If you add the [tag:language-lawyer] tag, that will tell people that you would like answers to be supported by quotes from the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undefined behavior.

The standard [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/language.support#propagation-9.sentence-1):

> ```
> [[noreturn]] void rethrow_exception(exception_ptr p);
> ```
>
> *Preconditions:* `p` is not a null pointer.
>
> *Throws:* The exception object to which `p` refers.

Violating a precondition is UB ([`[res.on.required]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#res.on.required-2)). Any behavior you could possibly observe is standard-compliant; the C++ standard places no constraints on what may happen. So don't do it.

Comment: To add: _20.5.4.11 Requires paragraph [res.on.required]
1 Violation of the preconditions specified in a function’s Requires: paragraph results in undefined behavior unless the function’s Throws: paragraph specifies throwing an exception when the precondition is violated._ (in the draft I have, it's _Requires_ instead of _Preconditions_, but same thing)

Comment: @ChrisMM Thanks, added. Since it's `Preconditions` and not `Requires`, the following paragraph is actually the one.

Comment: Must be a newer draft than the one I use (N4659) - it doesn't have `Preconditions`.